# How to use Linq in C# for parsing webpage using htmlagilitypack?

Tags: c#, linq, visual-studio, parsing, screen-scraping

Am trying to find tutorial on net that explains how to parse webpage(Wikipedia am working on), using Linq ... something like this that uses System.Linq :

```
var reviewBodyChildNodes = newsNode.ChildNodes
                                   .Single(x => x.Id == "review-body")
                                   .ChildNodes;
```

OR

```
newMovie.Title = div.Descendants()
                    .Where(i => 
                           i.Name == "h4" &&
                           i.GetAttributeValue("itemprop", "") == "name"
                    )
                    .FirstOrDefault()
                    .InnerText
                    .Trim();
```

But All I found is XmlDocument that uses xml data as an example and XmlElement... How is it different from above thing? What am I missing here? I want some explanations like on this page:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/691119/Html-Agility-Pack-Massive-information-extraction-f

Please Help.

Comment: well formed html should be pretty much the same as xml for linq-to-xml queries

Comment: Yup, but certain Xpath do not work at all ... Debugging breaks at the statement where DOM element is evaluated. I tried firebug, chrome tool ... Xpath is correct ... I simply dont knw how to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

Web Page Scraper's are specific to the web page you are getting data from.  I would think for someone to be able to use the htmlagilitypack you would have to know Linq and Regular Expressions well.  I can suggest a couple of resources to help you with that.  For learning Linq I like **LinqPad** which is a free tool with tons of examples in C# Linq, Linq To XML, Regular Expressions.

Link:   https://www.linqpad.net/